# Button in an while in PHP PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a select in mysql with PDO and make a list with the data returned, but I need to put a button in every "div", to alter the table, I tried to put a `if(isset($_POST['']))`, but obliviously it didn't work, I'm not getting any other way to do this.

```php
$stmt = $PDO -> prepare("SELECT idP, a, b, c, d, e FROM tblP inner join tblC WHERE idPP = ? and aP = 0 and fP = 0 and idCP = idC");
    $stmt -> bindParam(1, $_SESSION["idP"]);
    $stmt -> execute();

    $query = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

    $result = count($query);

    $query = array_chunk($query, $result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++){

        $idP = $query[0][$i][0];

        $dP = $query[0][$i][1];

        $lP = $query[0][$i][2];

        $nC = $query[0][$i][3]." ".$query[0][$i][4];

        $cC = $query[0][$i][5];

        echo '<div class="p2345">
             <h3>P ID:</h3><br><a>'.$idP.'</a> 
             <br><br> 
             <h3>Description of P:</h3><br>'. $dP.' 
             <br><br> <a href="'.$lP.'">Link of Archive</a> 
             <br><br> 
             <h3>N of the Cliente:</h3><br><a>'. $nC.' 
             <br><br> 
             <h3>C of the Cliente</h3><br><a>'. $cC.' 
             <br><br> 
             <input type="submit" name="btnC" value="Accept P">
             <input type="submit" name="btnR" value="Refuse P">  
             </div> 
             <br>'; 

        echo "--------------------------------------------";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because nothing is sending the post. Either use AJAX (javascript) or, well, put a  around the buttons... The form sends the POST or GET, not the button.

```
    echo '<div class="p2345">
         <h3>P ID:</h3><br><a>'.$idP.'</a> 
         <br><br> 
         <h3>Description of P:</h3><br>'. $dP.' 
         <br><br> <a href="'.$lP.'">Link of Archive</a> 
         <br><br> 
         <h3>N of the Cliente:</h3><br><a>'. $nC.' 
         <br><br> 
         <h3>C of the Cliente</h3><br><a>'. $cC.' 
         <br><br>
         <form method="post" action=""> 
           <input type="submit" name="btnC" value="Accept P">
           <input type="submit" name="btnR" value="Refuse P">   
         </form>
         </div> 
         <br>';
```

as for catching it, put this on top of your script;

```
if(isset($_POST['btnC'] || isset($_POST['btnR'])){
 //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Then I put the if(isset())?

Comment: Yeah, just put it on top of your script. Do you need an example?

Comment: If you can, I would be grateful.

Comment: I added something. Hope it helps!